# Получения значения, при клике на ListView и обработка в ViewModel Xamarin

Tags: listview, xamarin, viewmodel

Коллеги, приветствую! Помогите пожалуйста разобраться,
при нажатии на ListView, как узнать выбранное значение, (я его хочу сохранить  в отдельный список), пытаюсь реализовать логику обработки нажатия по типу ViewModel но не понимаю, как использовать забинденое событие на SelectedItem="{Binding SelectItem}"

Заранее благодарю за ответ

XAML страницы

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="App5.Views.KatalogLVPage">
<ListView x:Name="MyListView"

        ItemTapped="Handle_ItemTapped"
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectItem}"
        CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
          HasUnevenRows="True"
          ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsList}">

    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="{Binding ImageName}" WidthRequest="45" HeightRequest="60" />
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="18" />
                        <Label Text="{Binding CountOneitem}" />
                        <Label Text="{Binding Rub}" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>



</ListView>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Во **ViewModel** вам необходимо создать метод геттер/сеттер:

```
    private Item _selectedItem;
    public Item SelectItem
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedItem; 
        }
        set
        {
            _selectedItem = value;

            if (_selectedItem == null)
                return;

            YourMethod(item);

            SelectedItem = null;
        }
    }
```

Сеттер будет вызываться при **изменении** выбранного элемента.

**value** - элемент который был выбран

И не забудьте в **KatalogLVPage.cs** указать путь привязки:

```
public KatalogLVPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent(); 
            BindingContext = (ваша экземпляр ViewModel);
        }
```

Более подробно о паттерне MVVM и привязке можете узнать здесь:
https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-bindings-to-mvvm

Comment: Огромное спасибо, наподобие ответ встречал в интернете, но он замудренный был, тут все просто, благодарю за ответ! =)